# Define objects to only contain elements of specific type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I often use objects in JavaScript to ensure that a list of elements provides a unique key for each entry and to access elements by that key:

```
var obj = { key1: "anObject", key2: "anotherObject", ...};
```

Note that each entry has the same type (in this case it's a `string`).

How do I model this scenario with TypeScript? I need something like

```
var obj: {...DataType};
```

It means that an object can contain any number of attributes, which all share the same type.

Comment: Can you make your question title do more than just name a language and a feature? With 8.69 million questions on Stack Overflow, it is helpful when titles really describe the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typically use a proper map type for this, like ES6' `Map` or mori's `mori.hashMap`.

Anyway:

```
var obj: { [key: string]: string; };
```